# How to use Frame navigation on a SplitView with Prism?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, prism

I'm working with an UWP project that is using Prism to apply the MVVM pattern. I have a basic Frame like this:

```
<Frame   x:Name="SplitViewFrame" ></Frame>
```

With code behind, we can easily navigate this Frame:

```
SplitViewFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage),null);
```

But with MVVM we have to do it in ViewModel and I have no way to manage it. Does anyone know how to Navigate Frame in ViewModel with Prism?

Answer (score 1):

Prism's `NavigationService` has a reference to the frame to be able to do the navigation. This is [injected](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Navigation/FrameFacadeAdapter.cs#L26) during the application boot sequence. You can however create an [app shell](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/PrismApplication.cs#L260-L270) instead of the default single page navigation to support splitview/hamburger menu.

Have a look at the [SplitView sample](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/tree/master/SplitViewSample) in the Windows Samples repository. During startup, the CreateShell method is overridden to support the splitview.

```
    protected override UIElement CreateShell(Frame rootFrame)
    {
        var shell = Container.Resolve<AppShell>();
        shell.SetContentFrame(rootFrame);
        return shell;
    }
```

Note that you currently can't combine default page navigation and a splitview on e.g. page 3 in a single Prism `NavigationService`.